# How to set up your avatar in SourceTree.app?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I saw other people's image appears to the right of the commit message. How to set up that?

edit:
The GUI tools I am using is the SourceTree mac version.

Answer (score 69):

1. Go to http://en.gravatar.com/ create your account and upload the avatar image files that map to your emails.
2. Close Source Tree
3. Delete the cache file (or delete all files) inside path

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\cache\img

e.g. `C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\cache\img`

4. Open Source Tree. Now you got what you want!

Comment: I think on OS X the equivalent path is `~/Library/Application Support/SourceTree/ImageCache`

Answer (score 17):

If you're talking about Github, the profile image is being pulled from Gravatar (https://en.gravatar.com/).

Comment: although I am not talking about GitHub, but in SourceTree it's the same.

Comment: I think when I read it the first time, I read SourceTree as source tree, not catching that it was a specific product. :)

Comment: Still, your answer ir correct, [SourceTree uses gravatar](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/139733/please-help-how-do-i-change-avatar)

Comment: if *you* are talking about GitHub, then GitHub let its user to have their own avatar set through "Account Setting", not via Gravatar. For SourceTree, yes, it's Gravatar-fetched.

Answer (score 4):

There is an alternative solution for those who just want their Gravatar avatar to display as blank in Source Tree.

In the **SourceTree** App, navigate to **Tools** -> **Options**.

Then, under the '**General**' tab, under '**Commit Settings**' section, there is an option to use Gravatar.com or not.

'Load avatar images from gravatar.com'